# How these two approaches to spinors in curved spacetimes relate?

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, field-theory, spinors, dirac-matrices

Regarding spinors in curved spacetimes I have seem basically two approaches. In a set of lecture notes by a Physicist at my department he works with spinors in a curved spacetime $(M,g)$ by picking a vielbein $e^a_\mu$. In that setting a Dirac spinor is a $\Psi(x)\in\mathbb{C}^4$ with some properties.

1. It transforms under the Local Lorentz Symmetry as $$\Psi'(x)=L(\omega(x))\Psi(x),\quad L(\omega(x))=e^{\frac{i}{2}\omega^{ab}(x)\Sigma_{ab}},\quad \Sigma_{ab}=\dfrac{1}{4}[\gamma_a,\gamma_b],$$
   where $\gamma_a$ are the standard flat spacetime gamma matrices.
2. It can be covariantly differentiated as $$D_\mu\Psi(x)=\partial_\mu\Psi(x)+\dfrac{i}{2}B_\mu^{ab}\Sigma_{ab}\Psi(x)$$

On the other hand there is another approach which is more rigorous and relies on spin structures. In that sense we start with the bundle of orthonormal frames $\pi_F:{\cal F}(M)\to M$ and define a spin structure to be a principal ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$-bundle $\pi_P:P\to M$ together with a principal map $\Phi:P\to{\cal F}(M)$ such that if $\rho:{\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})\to {\rm SO}(1,3)$ is the covering map then $\Phi(e\cdot g)=\Phi(e)\cdot \rho(g)$. Now a Dirac spinor will be a section of the associated bundle to $P$ constructed from the Dirac representation of ${\rm SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

In this second approach one has to discuss whether a spin structure exists, the answer being that it exists if and only if the second Stiefel-Whitney class of $M$ is zero. A second question is whether the spin structure is unique and I'm aware that in some cases it is not. Now, to be honest I have not seem this spin structure definition being *used in practice*, so I know little more than the definition.

My question here is: *how does these two approaches relate*? The approach in the lecture notes seems way easier to use in practice, but I can't see where the spin structure lies in there. In particular it is not clear to me where the map $\Phi$ lies in there and how distinct spin structures may appear. Still I have the impression that we can start from the spin structure and reach a point in which to work in practice we get to the approach in the lecture notes.

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think the first approach describes spinors locally and says nothing about whether these structures can be extended globally on the entire manifold. The second approach defines spinors globally.

Answer (score 3):

The two definitions are equivalent once we think about what is required for the spinor field from the first to be mathematically well-defined:

If you want to say what sort of object the spinor field $\Psi$ is mathematically, it has to be a section of a (complex) vector bundle $S\to M$ with fiber $\mathbb{C}^4$ such that there is a consistent action of the spin group at every point. Since $L(\omega(x)) \in \mathrm{SO}(S_x)$ - the spin transformation acts as a special orthonormal transformation at every point of the bundle $S$ - this means we should consider a bundle with the spin group as a fiber that projects down onto the special orthonormal frame bundle of $S$: $p : P_\text{Spin}(S) \to P_\text{SO}(S)$ with $p(lg) = p(l)\pi(g)$ where $l\in P_\text{Spin}, g \in \text{Spin}(S)$ and $\pi : \text{Spin}(S) \to \mathrm{SO}(S)$ is the double covering.

Furthermore, physically, we want that the transformation of $\Psi$ happens "concurrently" to that of a vector - a rotation rotates both vectors and spinors, there are not different kinds of rotations that would act separately. So the bundle $P_\text{Spin}(S)$ above must also project down onto the special orthonormal frame bundle $P_\text{SO}(TM)$ of the manifold itself. $P_\text{Spin}(S)$ together with that projection is now the spin structure from your second definition.

Conversely, the spin structure from the second definition yields the spinor bundle $S$ and hence spinor fields as its sections via the usual [associated bundle construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_bundle).